BMO2 2015 Question 4: does a $100$-loop exist?
I've gotten stuck on question 4 from the 2015 BMO2:

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ with integer coordinates, we say that $P$ sees $Q$ if the line segment $PQ$ contains no other points with integer coordinates. An $n$-loop is a sequence of $n$ points
$P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n$, each with integer coordinates, such that the following conditions hold:
(a) $P_i$ sees $P_{i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, and $P_n$ sees $P_1$;
(b) No $P_i$ sees any $P_j$ apart from those mentioned in (a);
(c) No three of the points lie on the same straight line.
Does there exist a $100$-loop?

I noticed that non adjacent points must have at least one integer on the line between them not part of the set of points. But past that I'm unsure what I'm meant to do next.
Any suggestions would be appreciated as I can't seem to find a solution online.

You have to mess around a bit for these types of problems, try toy examples, e.g., can you find a $3$-loop? a $4$-loop? a $5$-loop? Does it get more difficult to add another point? Why? What are the constraints?

Hint: If $P_i = ( i, y_i)$, then we can guarantee condition 1 (Other than $P_n$ sees $P_1$) regardless of the choice of $y_i$. So, what does it mean that condition 2 is satisfied, and can we find such a system? $\quad$ So this gives us a set of 99 points that satisfies the requirements. How can we add in a $P_{100}$?  (Note: While it's tempting to use induction, it's hard to see how to go from a $k$ loop to a $k+1$ loop. This idea sidesteps that, by finding a most of a $k$ loop which we then extend to a $k$ loop.)

Thank you very much for the replies I’ll give it another go!
